# Compile Flutter iOS error in Runner settings

Tags: flutter

I want to compile Flutter app on iOS (android build goes well). flutter doctor show me no errors. But when I am trying to connect an app id (https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#register-a-bundle-id) "Open the App IDs page of your developer account." Here I have a popup message "Access unavailable. This resource is only for developers enrolled ..."

Also I get an error in xCode in Runner settings.

My Apple developer account is pending, cause I didnt add my credit card. Is it obligated? 
What should I do to continue without subscription?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your Bundle Identifier from "com.example" to a unique string. A good approach is to reverse your a domain url. So if you had mike-kylma.com you would write "com.mike-kylma.[APP NAME HERE]". It is to ensure that apps can be distinguished between even though the app name is not unique.

Comment: I changed to "com.mike-kylma.app", but the same errors. 1) Failed to create provisioning profile.
There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it. 2) No profiles for 'com.mike-kylma.app' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.mike-kylma.app'.

Comment: Why I could not open a page from Flutter manual - (https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#register-a-bundle-id) "Open the App IDs page of your developer account."